# About nth derivative of $e^{-\frac {1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f( x) =e^{-\frac {1}{x}}$.
> I want to calculate a general formula for $f^{( n) }( x)$.

I found regularity. I put
$$f\left( x\right) =e^{-\frac {1}{x}},g\left( x\right) =\frac {1}{x^{2}}.$$
Then
$$f'\left( x\right) =f\left( x\right) g\left( x\right)$$
$$g^{\left( n\right) }\left( x\right) =\left( -1\right) ^{n}n!x^{-(n-2)}$$
I use Leibniz formula.
$$\left( fg\right) ^{\left( n\right) }=\sum ^{n}_{k=0} {}_nC_{k}f^{(k)}g^{( n-k) }\\={}_nC_0fg^{n}+_{n}C_{1}f^{'}g^{\left( n-1\right) }+\ldots +f_{n}C_{n-1}\left( fg\right) ^{\left( n-1\right) }g +{}_{n}C_{n}\left( fg\right) ^{\left( n\right) }g$$
I don't know what to do next. Please tell me how to solve.

Comment: I think $f'(x) = \frac {e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x^2}$.

Comment: I have no idea if that's correct.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5En+%28e%5E%28-1%2Fx%29%29%2Fdx%5En

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your approach you may derive a recursive formula:
$$f^{(n)} (x) = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(f(x)x^{-2})=
\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}f^{(k)}(x)(x^{-2})^{(n-1-k)}\\=\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \binom{n-1}{k}f^{(k)}(x)(n-k)! (-1)^{n-k+1}x^{k-1-n}.$$
Then you can verify by induction that
$$f^{(n)} (x) =\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^{2n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n}{k} k!\,x^k.$$
As regards the integer sequence $a_{n,k}=\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n}{k} k!$ see the references at [OEIS A089231](https://oeis.org/A089231).

Comment: I was very easy to understand. Thank you!